# Legalities of compost toilets

Tags: composting, construction, toilet, law

Is there any compost toilet that is legal for new construction? Assuming the answer is no, will there ever be?

Comment: Where in the world are you asking about? We have dealt the [the legalities in the US previously](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/539/48)